# Scurvy grass - preparation and kitchen utensils

Tags: vitamins

So, as many of you may know, I live on a boat, traveling the world by sea.  Though today in most places it is possible to obtain at least some decent nutrition no matter where (Azores sometimes impossible), I am interested.  **Scurvy Grass, what is the best preparation for it and do I need any special utensils?**

I have found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochlearia#Uses) and [that](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/british/empire_seapower/captaincook_scurvy_01.shtml).

Comment: This is a recipe request d00g.

Comment: For the "what can I cook with it" part (which as GdD hints is off-topic) part, maybe you'd be willing to instead ask whether it's good cooked (or just raw) and what kinds of existing recipes you could add/substitute it into? For the "where can I find it"... it does look very much like this is something that's not at all commercially grown, so you'd have to forage? I suspect finding/identifying plants in nature is a bit outside our wheelhouse as well.

Comment: Cooking is oft implicated in destroying (at least some) vitamin C, so you might not want to...?

Comment: @Ecnerwal.  Good Point.  Perhaps, in order to retain the vit c I should have said 'eat - serve' with it etc...  Let's just say that the vit c is not important, and I just like the taste of scurvy grass - after all it's a free world...  isn't it?

Comment: Often an expensive one, in my experience, which I'd think you'd know since you have a hole in the water and those are commonly associated with throwing money in them (or standing fully clothed under a cold shower ripping up $100 bills, as a simulation...) ;-) I like wood sorrel, myself.

Comment: In our case a warm shower, as the sun is shining.  Shower?  Once a month all crew will have a wash 'whether they need it or not'!  And I can't remember the last time I saw a $100 bill!  As for your liking for wood sorrel - I applaud you and your choice of vit c edibles, I think that the next time I am in a general part of Europe of Asia I will look out for it - or maybe just go to any St Patrick's day event.

Comment: @GdD.  Sorry, will in a moment (after scouring the countryside for some edibles) look at changing the wording.

Comment: @dougal2.0.0, very good - you might want to pop into [chat] before, this question is currently discussed there.

Comment: Perhaps some slight rephrasing like "are there preparation methods to avoid"? Wanting to know what's "best" when there are several acceptable methods of preparation (e.g. uncooked vs steamed) isn't helpful but knowing that there might be a method that is utterly not recommended because it leads to an inedible (or nearly so) product might be more useful?

Comment: Also, I've spent several weeks in the Azores as my mom lived there for a couple of years and I thought their food was quite excellent. That white fresh cheese they make is beautiful and their seafood options are wonderful.

Comment: @Catija.  Depends where in the Azores and at what time of year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you look to [Rene Redzepi's new Nordic cuisine](http://noma.dk/), which sources the very type of ingredient(s) in which you're interested. [Common scurvy-grass grows](http://www.ecomare.nl/en/encyclopedia/organisms/plants/flowering-plants/crucifer-family/long-leaved-scurvy-grass/) along French, northern Spanish, Danish and Norwegian coasts and on mountain peaks in Western Europe. Weigh anchor and sail to the Basque Country coast, and search the Barbadun, Plentzia and Urdaibai estuaries.

Comment: again you come to my rescue, I'm thinking of keeping you on board as a just in case!!

Comment: Lucette?  No, wrong ocean.  But you are welcome as crew anytime.